# Log-Rank Test After Optimal Pair Matching

Tags: survival, paired-data, propensity-scores, matching

I have clinical data and used [optimal matching](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/method_optimal.html) in the MatchIt package to match cases to controls on several variables.  Matching was done in a 1:1 ratio, and balance was achieved.

I then did a Kaplan-Meier analysis with a log rank test in the R survival package.  A reviewer has said I need "the log rank test should be stratified by pairs."

I'm unclear why this is necessary - the only weights I'm seeing from the matching procedure are 0's and 1's.

Is there a way to "stratify by pairs" in R?

Any guidance to references is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimal matching returns pair membership in the `subclass` column of the `match.data()` output. This can be added to the log-rank test as a stratum variable using the following model formula:

```r
Surv(time, status) ~ treat + strata(subclass)
```

This is recommended to account for the paired nature of the matched sample and has nothing to do with the weights.

Comment: Thanks so much, Noah!